# Am getting error when am uploading the Image.(Magick::ImageMagickError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

Am getting error when am uploading the Image.

```
Magick::Image.read('/var/www/wavespot_builds/releases/20130423091328/public/splash_templates/10026/10017/Screenshot from 2014-03-10 14:26:39.png')
```

when i did like this am getting this type of error,

```
Magick::ImageMagickError: corrupt image `/var/www/wavespot_builds/releases/20130423091328/public/splash_templates/10026/10017/Screenshot from 2014-03-10 14:26:39.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3182
```

Help me, Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind to try to escape spaces?

Comment: i tried like that also, even though not working....

Comment: And the image is shown properly in any image viewer? I mean, are you sure it’s not corrupted?

Comment: yes,this error came. Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /var/www/wavespot_builds/releases/20130423091328/public/splash_templates/10026/10014/10547458_1498069360410740_2300522107711226754_n.jpg). That'sway am getting Magick::ImageMagickError: corrupt image error. These all are doing in production server, in my  local server every thing is working fine but in production am getting above error.

Comment: Assuming your production server root is `/var/www` you might want to try to ensure the directory structure is OK with simple browser request  to http://YOURDOMAIN/wavespot_builds/releases/20130423091328/public/splash_templates/10026/1‌0014/10547458_1498069360410740_2300522107711226754_n.jpg I would guess the image will not come up in browser, meaning you have a different directory structure and/or access rights on production server.